# how to run this code for image crawling with scrapy

Tags: image, scrapy, web-crawler

## newbie

I want to try to crawling images from a website with scrapy library

I found a code from github (https://github.com/imikay/ImageGrabber)
but how to run the code?
can someone tell me step by step please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone the repo - `git clone git@github.com:imikay/ImageGrabber.git`
Go to this folder - `cd ImageGrabber`
Here https://github.com/imikay/ImageGrabber/blob/master/ImageGrabber/spiders/ImageSpider.py we can see the code of spider. You need to rewrite it for your goal.
 Anyway, this code from 2011 and a better way to write a new project for your goal.